# how to get next day date and next month date using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to get next day date and next month date using jquery

I tried like following :

```
//FOR NEXT DAY
var dateString = 'Dec 17, 2013'; // date string
var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1);

//FOR NEXT MONTH
var dateString = 'Dec 17, 2013'; // date string
var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+30);
```

but which is not good practice :(

> please guide how can i get next day date and next month date using jquery function or any good method?

Comment: 1st - JS libraries are not DLLs. 2nd - You don't need to use jQuery to achieve such a simple task like this. It would be overkill. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @MelanciaUK oops i want to say references not dll's  :P 
okies i find my way i did it in controller method :)

Comment: Not sure why my comment recommending an excellent date & time library was deleted. If you're only doing any date/time manipulation in one or two places then I agree an extra library may be overkill. However, dates and times are a very complex thing, which you'll more likely than not get wrong on your own if you need to do a lot of it and it needs to be as accurate as possible - which is another great reason (in addition to the maintainability of the code) to use a library for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid dealing with the number of days in a month, the leap years and so on, use the Moment.js library (http://momentjs.com)

```
var d = new Date("2012/02/05");
var m = moment(d);
m.add('days', 1);
m.add('months', 1);
d = m.toDate();
```

Consider also that adding one month will not add the same amount of time depending on the current month.